# Linter complaining can't use the spread operator on string, which is good, but how do I avoid it in this situation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

When I hover over ...res in VSCode I get the warning from my linter:

> Spread types may only be created from object types

When I log res it's either a string or an object. However, I have no idea how to satisfy the linter in this case.

```
function getCookie(req: Request, key: string): string | undefined {
  const {
    headers: { cookie },
  } = req;

  return (
    cookie &&
    cookie.split(";").reduce<string | undefined>((res, item) => {
      const data = item.trim().split("=");

      return <string | undefined>{ ...res, [data[0]]: data[1] };
    }, "")
  );
}
```

Comment: Configure the inter so that it was your ally not your enemy. The idea behind linters is that they should help make good code, not that you should constantly fight them.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but how can you have an object of type `<string | undefined>`? What is the result supposed to actually look like?

Comment: There will be a string if there is a matching cookie, false if there is no matching cookie, and undefined if there are no cookies.

Comment: `<string | undefined>{ ...res, [data[0]]: data[1] }` <--- this type cast makes very little sense: you tell TS your object is either a string or an `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

So let's deal with the JavaScript and TypeScript aspects separately. In plain JavaScript terms, your function doesn't do what you've described. When there are cookies defined, it returns a `Record<string, string>` mapping cookie names to cookie values, not a particular string or `false`. If you mean for it to do something with `key`, you haven't included that part in your example.

When no cookies are defined, it ought to return `undefined`, but because you test the truthiness `cookies` in your return statement, it could return an empty string instead. That can be fixed by making that test separately and returning `undefined` explicitly. (Make sure your linter is warning you about using non-booleans in boolean context in TS.)

The reason you're spreading a string is that you're passing an empty string `""` as the initial value to [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Since you are accumulating objects, not strings, your initial value should be `{}` (an empty object) instead.

That helps us see the TypeScript issues. Your `string | undefined` casts are all unnecessary once the initial value is corrected, and the return type of the function overall becomes `Record<string, string> | undefined`. In sum:

```
function getCookie(req: Request, key: string): Record<string, string> | undefined {
    const {
        headers: { cookie },
    } = req;
    if (!cookie) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return cookie.split(";").reduce<Record<string, string>>((res, item) => {
        const data = item.trim().split("=");
        return { ...res, [data[0]]: data[1] };
    }, {});
}
```

However, if you actually want to look for a specific `key` and return its value, an array reducer isn't the best approach and your function would look rather different.